# Как остановить андроид сервис с через уведомление?

Tags: android, уведомления, android-notification

Как остановить сервис андроид через уведомление?

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID )
                    .setContentTitle("Alarm")
                    .setContentText(getString(R.string.n_text) + alarmHour.toString() + " : " + minute_string)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По нажатию на нотификашку вы должны отправлять интент в сервис, при получении которого сервис будет сам себя завершать.

Вот примерно так это должно выглядеть.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MusicNotificationBroadcastReceiver.class);
intent.setAction("STOP_ACTION");
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("Hello")
        .setTicker("Hello 2")
        .setContentText("Hello 3")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .build();
```

И соответственно в onStartCommand обработать этот интент

```
if(intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals("STOP_ACTION")) {
     stopForeground(true);
}
```

Comment: `"STOP_ACTION"` в первом примере кода почему-то отсутствует.

Comment: Поправил. Вы туда можете положить что-то другое